# Martingale optimal transport with two different nature of assets

Tags: option-pricing, martingale

In most of the litterature , for solving the optimal transport problem $sup_{Q\in \mathcal{M}}E^{Q}[c(S_{1},S_{2})]$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of probability coupling such that the marginals of Q verify $Q^{1} \sim S_{1}$ and $Q^{2} \sim S_{2}$ and the martingale condition $E^{P}[S_{2}|S_{1}] = S_{1}$ which means we consider the asset S at two different times as $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$

My question raises when it is not the same asset , like a payoff on a equity $S_{1}$ and FX $S_{2}$ , it would have no sens to consider the martingale condition defined as previously , we would rather want that each asset verifies it.
How do we account for this ? Do we introduce artificially $S^{1}$ as $(S^{1}_{1} , S^{1}_{0})$ and $S^{2}$ as $(S^{2}_{2},S^{2}_{0})$ and say that $E^[S^{1}_{1}|S^{1}_{0}]=S^{1}_{0}$ ? How would the choice of $S_{0}$ be relevant ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question for me? Are you looking to replace the asset with a portfolio containing some linear combination of assets? Or are you really interested in replacing S_1 with one asset and S_2 with a different one in the original formulation? In the former case, if the martingales are independent or defined on the same filtration then a linear combination of them is also a martingale, so we have the original problem. In the latter case we simply have a version of the non-martingale optimal transport problem which was formulated before the martingale version and well studied.

Comment: How do we account for the martingale constraint added in MOT when it's not one asset considered at two different times because indeed in this case $E^{P}[S_{2}/S_{1}] = S_{1}$ is "physically" understandable. If I had a payoff made of an FX and an equity , does $E^{P}[FX|Equity]$ has a practical sens ? We would like to have $E^{P}[FX|Equity] = Equity$ to respect the martingale condition which would seem completely strange to me. To bypass this i guess we would have to introduce extra information like the law of FX and Equity at time 0.